# Select a certificate for authentication always popping up also cuts internet

Tags: certificate, trusted-root-certificates

I have a Windows 11 OS with installed apps such as **Office and anti-virus (Kaspersky Premium)**. Previously, I downloaded **Adobe Acrobat (crack)** because I just needed to do a one-time activity using Acrobat after that I uninstalled the app. What I noticed is that after that *install-uninstall* of the product, I usually receive the pop-up message **"Select a certificate for authentication. Server:adobe.xxx"** which pops-up continuously to the point that sometimes when it shows, internet get cuts off. If I select install or click the OK button, everything goes good again.

Now I've read that removing all adobe certificate from trusted certificates will resolve this which I did. Unfortunately, the error was swapped with **o365 select certificate for authentication** and it does the same thing, pop-up every time and also cuts my internet.

What should I do to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Installing cracked software may compromise you system. The best action in such case for me is to reinstall everything and restore the user files from old (before installing cracked software) backup. And why you do not use trial version of Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: “What should I do to fix this?” - The crack made numerous unknown changes to your system. You should simply reinstall Windows

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the reply. I will just do this. Thanks.